# unknown collection class error when have sonata_type_collection in sonata_type_collection

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

#### Environment

Linux Mint 18

Sonata packages

```
$ composer show --latest 'sonata-project/*'
sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.26.0             3.26.0            
sonata-project/block-bundle              3.5.0              3.5.0             
sonata-project/cache                     2.0.0              2.0.0             
sonata-project/core-bundle               3.7.0              3.7.0             
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle           2.3.0              2.3.0             
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions       1.0.2              1.0.2             
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.1.7              3.1.7             
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle       2.2.0              2.2.0             
sonata-project/exporter                  1.7.1              1.7.1             
sonata-project/formatter-bundle          3.3.0              3.3.0             
sonata-project/media-bundle              3.8.0              3.8.0             
sonata-project/notification-bundle       3.2.0              3.2.0             
sonata-project/user-bundle               dev-master ff710b8 dev-master ff710b8
```

Symfony packages

```
$ composer show --latest 'symfony/*'
symfony/monolog-bundle     v3.1.2  v3.1.2  Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge     v3.3.13 v3.3.13 Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu      v1.6.0  v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill backporting apcu...
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu  v1.6.0  v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-r...
symfony/polyfill-mbstring  v1.6.0  v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring...
symfony/polyfill-php56     v1.6.0  v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some...
symfony/polyfill-php70     v1.6.0  v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some...
symfony/polyfill-util      v1.6.0  v1.6.0  Symfony utilities for portability...
symfony/security-acl       v3.0.0  v3.0.0  Symfony Security Component - ACL ...
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle v2.6.7  v3.1.6  Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony            v3.3.4  v3.3.13 The Symfony PHP framework
```

PHP version

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2017 13:49:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

### Subject

This issue is very similar as #1327 but I have not the same error.

I have "Survey Entity", "Question Entity" and "Choice Entity".

I have the class Admin for this different entity.

A survey entity have a list of question so it have a "sonata_type_collection" for this field.

```
->add('questions', 'sonata_type_collection', array("label" => false, "required" => true),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table'
                )
            )
```

A question have a list of choice and have a "sonata_type_collection" for this field too.

```
->add('choix','sonata_type_collection',array(),
                array(

                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table'
                ))
```

[image: screenshot-localhost 8000-2017-11-22-15-04-34]

If I remove, for choice field,

```
 array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table'
                ))
```

I have the form in "modal" and works but I don't want a "modal".

### Steps to reproduce

Create a field "sonata_tyoe_collection" in an other "sonata_type_collection" with table option.

### Expected results

A new form for create a choice.

### Actual results

[image: screenshot-localhost 8000-2017-11-22-15-14-29]

Comment: The same happens to me. If you persist only the Survey and question entity the first time, then if it allows you to add "choices" as a collection (when you edit later) but not before. The ideal would be to save everything at once but it is impossible to paint in line the second level of collection when creating a survey from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I managed to solve it adding a constructor just like this:

```
/**
* Survey constructor.
*/
public function __construct()
{
    $this->questions = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```